# ¿Cómo enviar un array con mysqli a Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli, pdo

nuevamente tengo un nuevo problema, resulta que cuando intento enviar un array a AJAX para que me aparezca unos datos en datatable no se envía si está con MySQLi, pero si está con PDO si lo manda bien, ¿Cómo soluciono esto para que me pueda enviar por JSON los datos a AJAX mediante consulta hecha con MySQLi a la base de datos. Más adelante les dejo los código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar!

Código con PDO el cual si me envía bien a AJAX/JS y me lo muestra bien en la base de datos:

```
include_once "conexionpdo.php";

    $objeto = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

    $opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
    $opcion = 1;
    switch ($opcion) {
    case 1:
        $estado_activo = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">ACTIVO</span>';
        $estado_inactivo = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">INACTIVO</span>';
        $estado_error = '<span class="bagde badge-pill badge-warning">ERROR</span>';
        $nombre = 'u.nombre u.apellido';
        $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.email, r.nombre_grupo, CASE WHEN u.estado = 1 THEN '$estado_activo' WHEN u.estado = 0 THEN '$estado_inactivo' ELSE '$estado_error' END as estado, u.fecha_registro FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN grupos_usuarios r ON u.grupo = r.id");
        $sql->execute();
        $data=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    }
    print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Código con MySQLi que no me envía nada a AJAX y la tabla me aparece vacía:

```
include_once "conexion.php";

    $opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';

    switch ($opcion) {
        case 1:
            $sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT u.id, u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.email, r.nombre_grupo, u.estado, u.fecha_registro FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN grupos_usuarios r ON u.grupo = r.id");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                $data["data"][] = $row;
            }
            break;

    }

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Y este es mi archivo JS con el que hago el llamado a AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user_id, opcion;
    opcion = 1;

    Tabla = $('#tablausuarios').DataTable({
        "language": {
          "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "ajax":{
            "url": "config/crudfinal.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {opcion:opcion},
            "dataSrc":""
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "nombre"},
            {"data": "usuario"},
            {"data": "email"},
            {"data": "nombre_grupo"},
            {"data": "estado"},
            {"data": "fecha_registro"},
            {"defaultContent": "<a title='Editar Usuario' class='badge badge-info'><i style='color:white' class='fa fa-edit'></i></a><a title='Eliminar Usuario' class='badge badge-danger'><i style='color:white' class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema por favor.

Comment: En PDO no le estás poniendo la clave `data` al array, mientras que en `mysqli` sí, intenta cambiar esto: `$data["data"][] = $row;` por esto: **`$data[] = $row;`**  o si no debes cambiar la forma de leer la respuesta en Javascript/Ajax, conforme a lo que estás devolviendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad es que la experiencia no se puede comparar con nada.

Comment: De nada. ¿Pudiste resolverlo con eso?

Comment: Si lo pude resolver, tan pequeño detalle que me daba tan gran problema, solo quisiera saber algo más que formularé en una nueva pregunta

Comment: PEro @A.Cedano eso no explica que reciba "nada" a menos que se refiera a que no se dibujaba nada en el front y él no revisó la consola. OP mira también que en un código pones la opción como 1 en duro, en el otro se apegas al parámetro recibido o la dejas como ''

Comment: @ffflabs como dices, es posible que estuviera recibiendo los datos, pero con otra estructura, al haber agregado la clave `data`, por eso le decía al final de mi comentario: *... o si no debes cambiar la forma de leer la respuesta en Javascript/Ajax, conforme a lo que estás devolviendo.*